# Postgresql invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table error

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I want to run this query but PostgreSQL gives an "invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table ua" error all the time.

```
WITH Student as (
    SELECT COUNT(user_id) as Count,user_id
    FROM user_role 
    WHERE deleted_flag = false
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 1 
    ORDER BY user_id
)
UPDATE user_account ua
SET university_id = university_id || 'S'
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN user_role ur ON ua.user_id = ur.user_id AND ur.deleted_flag = false AND ur.role_id = 10;
WHERE ua.user_id = s.user_id;
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Conditions on `ua` need to be in the `WHERE` clause.  You can switch to a "real" join condition by using `s.user_id`:

```
UPDATE user_account ua
    SET university_id = university_id || 'S'
    FROM Student s INNER JOIN
         user_role ur
         ON s.user_id = ur.user_id AND ur.deleted_flag = false AND ur.role_id = 10;
    WHERE ua.user_id = s.user_id;
```